# Using Mathematica to solve this differential equation

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, differential-equations

I want to describe the kinetics of a chemical reaction and my idea of a reaction model results (simplified) in a differential equation of the following form:

```
y1'(t)=y1(t)+y2(t)
```

where y1 is the from an experiment measured concentration of a reactant and y2 the measured concentration of a product over time. The differential equation has the following boundary conditions:

```
y1(0) = A
y2(0) = 0
```

now I couldn't solve the equation on my own, therefore, I tried to use Mathematica, but I always get an error when applying the second boundary condition:

```
In:  DSolve[{y'[t] == k*y[t] + k2*y2[t], y[0] == A, y2[0] == 0}, y[t], t]
Out: DSolve::deqx: Supplied equations are not differential equations of the given functions.
```

Does that mean that this differential equation has no analytical solution? Anyone has an idea?

Thanks in advance!

Best regards
Manuel

Answer (score 0):

You only have one equation to solve a simultaneous equation.

For example, this works:-

```
vars = {x[t], y[t]};
eqns = {x'[t] == y[t], y'[t] == x[t]};
inits = {x[0] == 1, y[0] == 0};
DSolve[eqns, vars, t] // Simplify
sol = vars /. DSolve[Join[eqns, inits], vars, t][[1]]
Plot[sol, {t, 0, 2}]
```

But your simultaneous equation is underdetermined.

```
vars = {y[t], y2[t]};
eqns = {y'[t] == k*y[t] + k2*y2[t]};
inits = {y[0] == A, y2[0] == 0};
DSolve[eqns, vars, t] // Simplify
```

> DSolve: There are more dependent variables than equations, so the system is underdetermined.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanation!